# Tiles not following input in a branching board game path

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a board game in Unity with multiple branching paths where the players can decide which one to follow. (Think the Mario Part game board) But the player input on which path to follow isn't working.

So I have a script that has the tokens follow a set path and (Linked List for the path) with a for loop to have the tokens move their allocated amount. Within the loop, I have an If statement that checks how many paths the tile has and if there are more than one if runs a separate script that pauses the game and offers a menu prompt for the players to pick one path or the other.

I've tried tossing in a few contitions for continuing the game within the loop but they either ignore the player input, are an input behind or just break the code.

```
    `for (int i = 0; i < spacesToMove; i++)
        {
            if (final_Waypoint == null)
            {
                final_Waypoint = Starting_Waypoint;
            }
            else
            {
                if (final_Waypoint.Next_Waypoint == null || final_Waypoint.Next_Waypoint.Length == 0)
                {
                    //we are overshooting the final waypoint, so just return some nulls in the array
                    //just break and we'll return the array, which is going to have nulls at the end.
                    Debug.Log(Current_Waypoint);
                    break;
                }
                else if (final_Waypoint.Next_Waypoint.Length > 1) // && if playerID == 0 so it only appears for players.
                {
                    menu.Pause_for_Choice();
                    //if (menu.ButtonPress == true)
                    final_Waypoint = final_Waypoint.Next_Waypoint[menu.choice_int]; 
                    //***There's a bug here. It calls menu as per normal, and the game pauses.
                    //But when I click 'no', choice_int isn't updated first: this function finishes first,
                    //so this function gets old choice_int. THEN the button function executes.
                    Debug.Log("test 3 " + menu.choice_int);

                }
                else
                {
                    final_Waypoint = final_Waypoint.Next_Waypoint[0];
                }
            }

            listOfWaypoints[i] = final_Waypoint;
            Debug.Log("i:" + i);

        }
        return listOfWaypoints;
    }`


`{
    public GameObject choice_Menu;
    public bool isPaused = true;
    public int choice_int=0;
    public int choice_placeholder = 0;


    public void Pause_for_Choice()
    {
        isPaused = true;
        choice_Menu.SetActive(true);
        Time.timeScale = 0;
    }

    public void Yes()
    {
        choice_placeholder = 0;
        UnPause_Game();
    }

    public void No()
    {
        choice_placeholder = 1;
        UnPause_Game();
    }

    public void UnPause_Game()
    {
        isPaused = false;
        choice_Menu.SetActive(false);
        Time.timeScale = 1;
    }
}`
```

Comment: Can't find any lines of code about user input.

Comment: Tight, thanks forgot to include the other script

Comment: Why did it change thanks to tight?

Comment: Nope, Im guessing it was "Right" to "Tight" :P